# Google Json Api without using Oauth

Tags: ios, json, google-cloud-storage

I want to use the Google JSON API for an iOS app. But I would I to do it without user authentication as there would be no sensitive data being stored. So I was hoping to use the public API key described here 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing

Heres the request url:

```
    NSString* text = self.textField.text;

NSString* data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message=%@", text];

NSData* postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString* length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
request.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject&key=myApiKey"];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (conn) {
    NSLog(@"connection successful");
}else {
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}
```

using this tho, i get a 401 Login Required Error.

What am I missing?

Comment: I updated my answer ..  please see below

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to upload an object anonymously into a bucket. This is not allowed by default, since it means that anyone who knows about your bucket would potentially be able to upload as many objects as they like without limit into your bucket.

Nonetheless, if you're comfortable with that possibility, it's certainly possible. Granting all users WRITE permission on the bucket will allow the call in your question to succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, how is this different from how Amazon DyanmoDB works where all you need is a Identity Pool id?, anyone who has that ID would have access to the data right? I was hoping to avoid the user authentication phase by using the public API key, but I guess that wont do

Comment: Amazon Identity Pool IDs are a bit different from API keys. API keys identify the project being used for accounting purposes, but they confer no security privileges. Google's equivalent to an identity pool ID is a "service account," which is an account that represents an application and can be granted read or write privileges like any other user. You do need to use authorization to act as a service account, though.

Answer (score 1):

From [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing):

> When your application requests private data, the request must be authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data.
>
> When your application requests public data, the request doesn't need to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier, such as an API key.
>
> Every request your application sends to the Google Cloud Storage JSON API needs to identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify your application: using an OAuth 2.0 token (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the application's API key.

As you are trying to make a public request, you just need to create an API key and use it instead of `key=API_KEY` as you are doing.

**Update**

You need to use OAuth2.0 token because in your case you are making an upload request. As @jterrace mentioned, an API key is not a form of authentication, so it's not enough to complete the request successfully.

Comment: yes i am using an actual key that i created, i just didn't want to post it on stackoverflow for everyone to look at

Comment: Of course ... so, I ask you to post a little more about your request code. Are you using `POST` instead of `GET` to make the request? How about the POST contents?

Comment: The API key is not a form of authentication.

Comment: @FormigaNinja I posted all the code i have that deals with the request

Comment: @jterrace would you mind elaborating on that? the documentation clearly says i could use OAuth2.0 and/or API key